# How to prove a centraliser is divisible by $3$ and use this to deduce the existence of an element of order $21$?

Tags: group-theory

I have got this question and I am stuck on the last part of the question.

I cannot show $|C_G(Z)|$ is divisible by $3$. By part f) it would suffice to show that $|\text{Ker} (\theta)|$ was divisible by $3$ but I don't know how to show that either.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The automorphism group of $Z$ is of order $6$ because the automorphisms of $Z \cong C_7 = \{0,1,\dots,6\}$ are precisely the maps $1 \mapsto n$ for $n = 1,\dots,6$.

By the first isomorphism theorem, the kernel of $\theta$ has size equal to $\frac{|G|}{|\mathrm{Im}(\theta)|}$, where the image is of size $1,2,3$ or $6$ since it divides $6$. But $|G|$ is odd, so the image can only have size $1$ or $3$. Therefore the kernel has size $63$ or $21$.

Comment: I am still not seeing this. I understand the first Iso theorem but I don't see the following?

1) How do we know the automorphism group has order $6$? 
2) You say the image has size $1,2,3,6$ but then only say the kernel has 2 possible values surely it has $4$ corresponding to the $4$ sizes of the images?

Comment: Expanded. I have only one hand at the moment so am trying to conserve typing.

Comment: Okay it makes sense now. Any hints for showing the existence of an element of order $21$?

Comment: @RyanS Alan Wang's answer shows that well.

Answer (score 1):

I continue from the answer of Patrick Stevens.

Since $|C_G(Z)|$ is divisible by $3$, by Cauchy's Theorem, there is an element $x\in C_G(Z)$ where $|x|=3$.

Since $|Z|=7$, by Cauchy's Theorem again, there is an element $y\in Z$ where $|y|=7$.

Since $x\in C_G(Z), xy=yx$. And also since $(|x|,|y|)=1$, we have $|xy|=|x||y|=21$, so $xy$ is an element of order $21$ in $G$.